# Does attracting Reapers to a Solar System only affect me?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Scanning too much in a system attracts Reapers which case you. However, does attracting Reapers mean they only care about *you* or could attracting them to important solar systems actually cause harm to any planets/people in the game?

Basically, does attracting Reapers have any effect beyond the risk of a Game Over if they touch me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the Reapers are already in control of these systems when you enter - scanning just draws attention to the Normandy.

If you scan too often, they'll pursue you, but they're already tearing it up in the system, so there's no additional risk to others.  If anything, you're *distracting* them slightly.

Comment: K, so I'll never have access to a solar system that isn't Reaper controlled?

Comment: @BenBrocka, no, you do in some cases.  For instance, the Citadel's system is not Reaper controlled (at least as far as I've been in the game).  You can scan to your heart's content in that system and nothing will ever happen.  On the galaxy map, the Reaper controlled systems have a "Reaper" on top of their icons.  If there's no Reaper icon, there's no Reapers.

Comment: Yeah, I know about the Citadel, but wasn't sure if any other systems would pop up.

Comment: @BenBrocka, I've seen at least a couple more, but to date I haven't found anything in the non-Reaper controlled systems by scanning.  I think the two mechanics go hand-in-hand, although I won't be able to confirm until I test it exhaustively.